# Can't Scroll SectionList Until Last Item Because Out of Viewport

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have issue with a long sectionlist that went off outside of viewport, how can I make it work normally? I have tried using `flexShrink:1` but it didn't work. other solution I have tried is using `<ScrollView>` but it giving me error `VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.` I really need help for this issue, how to make the SectionList stay inside and work normally? here is some example code I have tried

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import AnotherJS from "./AnotherJS";

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{backgroundColor:"#5273B7", flex:1, padding:10}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:"#ff0000", borderTopLeftRadius:10, borderTopRightRadius:10, padding: 10}}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor:"#ffffff", borderRadius:10}}>
            <Text>Picker Here</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:"#00ff00", flex:1, borderBottomLeftRadius:10, borderBottomRightRadius:10, padding:10}}>
          <View style={{flexShrink:1}}>
            <AnotherJS/>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**AnotherJS.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {View, Text, SectionList } from "react-native";
import Accordion from "react-native-collapsible/Accordion";

const dataArray = [
  { title: "Info 1",
    content: [
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
    ] },
  { title: "Info 2",
    content: [
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
    ] },
  { title: "info 3",
    content: [
      { title: "1", data: ["1"]},
      { title: "2", data: ["2"]},
    ] }
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

export default class AnotherJS extends Component {
  state = {
    activeSections: [0],
  };

  _renderHeader = (section) => {
    return(
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        padding: 10,
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center" ,
        backgroundColor: "#A9DAD6" }}>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}>{section.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderContent = (section) => {
    return(
      <SectionList
          sections={section.content}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <Text>{title}</Text>
          )}
        />
    );
  };

  _updateSections = (activeSections) => {
    this.setState({ activeSections });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flexShrink:1}}>
        <Accordion
          sections = {dataArray}
          activeSections = {this.state.activeSections}
          renderHeader = {this._renderHeader}
          renderContent = {this._renderContent}
          onChange = {this._updateSections}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your list component in a container.

```
  _renderContent = (section) => {
    return(
<ListContainer style={{flex: 1}}> // you can add borders for clarity
      <SectionList
          sections={section.content}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <Text>{title}</Text>
<ListContainer/>
          )}
        />
    );
  };
```

ListContainer code:

```
const ListContainer = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
`;
```

Comment: what is `<ListContainer>`? I cant find it in react native documentation, could you explain it?

Comment: I use styled component instead stylesheets. To speed up the writing of the example, I have inserted a flex style to speed up the coding for the ListContainer.

Comment: could you give me the example code of <ListContainer>?

Comment: `     const ListContainer = styled.View`     flex: 1; `;    `